# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method' when calling my get method

Tags: python, django

When calling my get method on an URL on Postman, I get :

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string,
  a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Code:

```py
 def get_payment_scheduler(self, id):
     userAccount = AccountManager.objects.get(id = id) 
     payment_scheduler = PaymentScheduler.objects.get(userAccount=userAccount)
     if payment_scheduler.exists():
        return payment_scheduler[0]
     return None
```

AccountManager and PaymentSchedule have a one to one field

Expecting something like this :

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "purchaserId": null,
    "subscriptionDate": "2019-09-27",
    "validityDate": null,
    "offer": "Free offer",
    "priceTTC": "12.00",
    "tva": "0.00",
    "priceHT": "0.00",
    "hasSubscribed": true,
    "reader": "readerId"
}
```

Comment: please add the full traceback. there is no call to `int` anywhere in the snippet you've provided, so it's not clear what might be raising this error. please include additional code as [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I think, it's because `id` is a function of python and you maybe forgot to give an argument to your url call with postman. If you open a python console, you can see the `id` declaration:

```py
>>>id
<built-in function id>
```

You should use another variable name in order to have a better error message.